# Branch of Math That Links Indicator Function and Expressability in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, ring-theory, special-functions

If we have a commutative ring $R$ with identity, then all of the functions from $R$ to $R$ is defined as:
$$f(x)=\sum_{p \epsilon R}I_{\{p\}}(x)f(p)$$
(I have a related post here validating this series: [Expressing real function algebraically for every point in its domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562575/expressing-real-function-algebraically-for-every-point-in-its-domain))

If the indicator function $I_{\{p\}}(x)$ is expressible by the operations in the ring $R$, then that should mean that all functions in $R$ are expressible in the operations in $R$ (A simple statement that follows from the series definition above).

So my question is: ***What branch of math most closely contains this idea? Is there a generalization?***

To me, it seems that the concept of "expressibility" is related to some logic branch of math. However, i present the above series in the context of algebra.

Comment: This sum doesn't make sense in a general ring. For it to make sense, the ring would have to be finite; or it should have some topology to define convergence of an infinite sum; or at least some additional structure to be able to define this sum properly

Comment: @Max Is the topology still necessary? For some x, only one term (or none) in the series would not be "0". I believe this leaves topology as just another structure that would not change how the sum results. Is there any structure that i can add that would make the sum 'converge' without mentioning topology?

Comment: @user512716 you could restrict to functions with finite support.

Answer (score 2):

> What branch of math most closely contains this idea?

Based on what we are talking about in the comments, there needs to be some mechanism to make the sums well-defined, and one way I suggested was to restrict to functions of finite support. So I think the best match is:

**Group rings**

For a group $G$ and a ring $R$, you can consider the set of functions $G\to R$ of finite support, and collectively they form a ring under certain operations.

The group elements are indeed "indicator functions" for elements of $G$.